# Magmi doesn't seem to update the price index?

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, indexing, magmi, reindex

We've used Magmi for some time, and have been experiencing an issue where the price of our uploads changes at product level, i.e. if you navigate to the frontend product page, or admin backend page of the product you have just updated, the price displays correctly. So we're referring to the list price (attribute name price) and the sale price (attribute name special_price). All fine so far.

BUT when you add the item to cart and navigate to the shopping basket, the price displayed in the cart, is still the old price before the Magmi profile ran and changed the price.

To fix this short term, we found that manually updating any attribute of that product from the Magento backend for that product, or on mass from the product grid, fixes the issue, and the correct price is displayed in the cart as well as on the product page.

But this isn't a great solution! We've tried changing the various configuration check box settings in Magmi but nothing seems to work.... e.g. Magmi Optimiser or Magmi Magento Reindexer or On the Fly Indexer....

Any ideas on how to fix or even how to debug? Thanks.

Comment: You have any customization on product prices? I don't see how it's possible for the price fields (`price` and `special_price`) to be updated correctly, while adding to cart somehow brings up values that have been updated supposedly. The only advice I can provide is getting all of your local and community extensions disabled and running the whole process to check if prices display correctly in the cart.

Answer (score 2):

Magmi directly updates the database, bypassing Magento methods to gain significant speed improvement. It's highly likely that there are associated Magento methods that run to update the price indices when you do a proper product save.

You can spend time to find out what exactly is run to update the prices, but there isn't a simple way to overcome Magmi's downside simply because the nature of it. You win some and lose some. However, reindexing Magento may update the prices correctly. You can either try reindexing just the price or the whole thing.

Run from the terminal in `magento_root/shell` directory:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Or

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

Comment: Magmi includes a built in indexer, so there really is no downside here.  The user said that he tried the indexer and it's not working, which probably means there's a configuration issue on his end.

Comment: It comes back to my recommendation. Try the Magento indexer, not the Magmi indexer. It's possible there's customization that's not compatible.. in which case you should disable all extensions and see if Magmi works as you think it should.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's not an index thing though. Like I say the prices update in the backend of the product, and in the frontend too. They update straight away. The problem is at the shopping cart. The price still stays as the old price, even after price index re-running from Magento admin, and from Magmi. The only way I've found to solve so far is manually update and attribute on all the products from the csv file we've just updated. It may be a configuration setting like Axel mentions above, but we've tried every combination of Magmi settings relevant, and no joy :(